# Anchor at the baseline of the last line for a tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I'd like to place a node with multi-line text using as anchor the eastmost point at the baseline of the last line, without having to manually break the lines. Specifying the node text width breaks this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \x in {1, 4, 7}
  \draw (\x,-1) -- (\x,1);
\node[anchor=base east, 
      align=right, 
      ] at (1,0) {some text some\\text some text};
\node[anchor=base east, 
      align=right, 
      text width=3cm
      ] at (4,0) {some text some text some text};
\node[anchor=base east, 
      align=right, 
      text width=3cm
      ] at (7,0) {some text some\\text some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd expect something like the second option to do what I want. Is this doable in some other way? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 6):

You could use a parbox inside the node. Then you can set its baseline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \x in {1, 4, 7}
  \draw (\x,-1) -- (\x,1);
\node[anchor=base east,
      align=right,
      ] at (1,0) {some text some\\text some text};
\node[anchor=base east,
      align=right,
      draw=red,inner sep=0pt
      ]  at (4,0) {\parbox[b]{3cm}{some text some text some text}};
\node[anchor=base east,
      align=right,
      text width=3cm,
      ] at (7,0) {some text some\\text some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]